# Is it good practice to pass multiple references to the same object into a method?

Tags: java

If you have:

```
class Component
{ 
   public Component(Interface1 interface1Instance, Interface2 interface2Instance)
   {

   this.interface1Instance = interface1Instance;
   this.interface2Instance = interface2Instance;

   }
}
```

then in the class which you use this in:

```
class ComponentGroup implements Interface1, Interface2
{
    public ComponentGroup()
    {

    this.component = new Component(this, this);

    }

}
```

While using composition, is it good practice to pass the same instance as separate parameters for to the component?

(edited):

Is it better to do what I presented above or to:

```
class Component
{ 
   public Component(Object object)
   {
       if(object instanceof Interface1){
           this.interface1Instance = interface1Instance;
       }
       if(object instanceof Interface2){
           this.interface2Instance = interface2Instance;
       }

   }
}
```

and

```
class ComponentGroup implements Interface1, Interface2
{
    public ComponentGroup()
    {

    this.component = new Component(this);

    }

}
```

Comment: For what reason?

Comment: Sure. e.g passing many ints or Integers to a method. You can also pass an array - if you need to pass multiple instances or the same class.

Comment: For the reason of composition @SpencerWieczorek

Comment: Composition doesn't require multiple instances of the same class.

Comment: Two instances of the same object no. Two different objects of the same type, that's fine.

Comment: Note that when you pass `(this, this)` you are **not** passing two objects, you are passing two *references* to the *same* object. If you have an object that implements multiple interfaces, this can be totally legitimate.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your case the first example is better design, because in the second example you are not specifying what Interfaces need to be passed as parameters to Component. Having a parameter of type Object is not good practice since other users of your class will have to read the constructor to know what should be passed in.

If you always use these two interfaces together you should combine them. Or if you're not the author, then create an abstract class A that inherits from both and have Component take an object of type A as a parameter.